# Automatically Resize iFrame created using document.write

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iframe

So, I have a Javascript file:

```
function resize(id) {
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;
    id = id.trim();

    if (document.getElementById) { 
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + 'px';
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + 'px';
}

document.write("<iframe frameborder='0' id='vote-frame' scrolling='no'></iframe>")
$("#vote-frame").attr("src", "<%= server_embed_url(@server) %>");
$("#vote-frame").load(function(){ 
    resize("vote-frame")
})
```

This should write an iFrame to the page, and resize it based on the width/height of the content in the iFrame, but for some reason that is not working.

I'm displaying the script on my page with:

```
%script{src: server_display_url(@server, format: :js)}
```

Is this a limitation of Rails' .js.erb, or is it just not possible because the iFrame is being created dynamically by document.write?

I should probably mention that this all works fine when I put the iFrame directly into the HAML view, and it resizes just fine.

EDIT: I also tried the usual onload attribute in the iFrame tag:

```
function resize() {
    var id = "vote-frame"
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if (document.getElementById) { 
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + 'px';
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + 'px';
}
document.write("<iframe frameborder='0' onload='resize()' src='<%= server_embed_url(@server) %>' id='vote-frame' scrolling='no'></iframe>")
```

For some reason, it's still not resizing...

Comment: Have you checked the javascript console?  What I think is probably happening is that the browser isn't getting a chance to render the html you added with document.write until AFTER your next two operations.  Try putting those bottom two in a setTimeout with a 0 delay.  This will force those operations to use the event loop, which should queue them AFTER the rendering of the iframe.

Comment: @JamesM.Lay See my edit. I tried to go with the usual onload attribute in the iFrame tag, so it would run resize() when it loads, but it's still not resizing. Could this be the same reason?

Comment: Where you set the height and width, either remove the 'px' or change .height and .width to .style.height and .style.width.  It's trying to set an html attribute using css values.

Comment: Also, you absolutely must tell us what kind of errors the js console is giving you.  Press F12 when you run this page on your browser.  Since you're dealing with frames, this could be a CORS error.  Also, using the onload still will not work, because you will get "resize  is undefined".  I just tested it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adm64cLu/1/)